# Is there a way to fix the numerical error in the solution I have for the integer Palindrome problem?

Tags: python-3.x

Here's my code for checking if a given number is palindrome or not:

```
def intPalindrome(num): 
    
    if num <= 0: 
        return num == 0   
    
    cur_num = num 

    while cur_num > 0: 
        
        lsd = cur_num % 10 
        num_digits =  round(math.log(cur_num, 10)) + 1 
        msd = cur_num // math.pow(10, num_digits-1)

        if lsd != msd: 
            return False
        else: 
            cur_num = cur_num - msd * math.pow(10, num_digits-1)
            # cur_num %= math.pow(10, num_digits-1) # this also gives the same error! 
            cur_num //= 10 

    return True
```

Now, when I test this code

```
print(intPalindrome(1212121212121212121), end='\n\n') # numerical error I think 
print(intPalindrome(121212121), end='\n\n')
```

I get:

```
False
True
```

I think it's because of numerical precision error. Can anyone tell me the issue and fix to this solution?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried printing `lsd`, `msd`, and `cur_num` at each step?

Comment: If you use `log()`, don't be surprised to get precision errors...

Comment: Yes, lsd and msd are different. So I thought that lsd is wrong.  In that case the modulus operator is not correct?

Comment: ok that makes sense but then how to fix this issue? @Breakingnotsobad

Comment: One easy solution is to convert the num to a string

Comment: that adds additional space complexity of O(n). That was my first brute-force try.

Comment: Ah... there are space constraints...

Comment: @Selcuk any thoughts?

Comment: Adding another num is ok? In this case add numcopy = num and num2 = 0, loop on (num != 0), take x = num % 10, num2 = num2*10 + x, num /= 10 ; then compare if numcopy and num2 (num reversed) are equal. Or you could do another %10 loop just to count the digits, without using log(). (using // and not / of course) And another loop to get the 10s ... (not using pow())

Answer (score 1):

Since you're dealing with integers, you should avoid using `math.pow`, which always returns a `float` and introduces floating point errors when you perform further operations with it.

Instead, use the `**` operator, which returns an integer when only integer operands are involved.

That is, change both of the usages of:

```
math.pow(10, num_digits-1)
```

to:

```
10 ** (num_digits - 1)
```

Alternatively, you can work around the small floating point errors by using the `round` function just like you do with the returning value of `math.log`:

```
round(math.pow(10, num_digits - 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

We also remember that there is `%` symbol which is:

> remainder of x / y

In Python 3, number / 10 will try to return a float. However, floating point values can't be of arbitrarily large size in Python and if number is large an `OverflowError` will be raised.

for example when debug your code I see:`print(intPalindrome(1212121212121212121)`

```
lsd = 6.0 # OverflowError: integer division result too large for a float
msd = 2.0
```